# Saving int values to SD and read them

Tags: android

I have succesfully saved int values to sd but cant read. It always gives numberformat information. I made all logics, but cant find why it gives error.

Here is my code ;

this my constant

```
private final static String EXTERNAL_FILES_DIR = "ARDROID";
private final static String FILE_NAME = "turkcell.txt";
private boolean isThereAnySavedFile = false;
```

when this method called, it tries to open file, if file does not exist, create the file

```
public void anySavedDataInSD() {
    String textFromSD = String.valueOf(read());
    if (isThereAnySavedFile) {
        int numberOfSendedSMS = Integer.parseInt(textFromSD.toString());
        numberOfSendedSMS++;
        writeToSD(String.valueOf(numberOfSendedSMS));
    } else {
        int first=60;
        String g = String.valueOf(first);
        writeToSD(g);
    }
}
```

this method for writing

```
private void write(File file, String msg) {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        outputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
        Logger.info("oldu bu kez");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.info("oldu bu kez2" + e);
    } finally {
        Logger.info("oldu bu kez3");
        try {
            if (outputStream != null)
                outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException exception) {

        }
    }
}
```

this methof for reading

```
public StringBuilder read() {
    StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        File externalFilesDir = getExternalFilesDir(EXTERNAL_FILES_DIR);
        File file = new File(externalFilesDir, FILE_NAME);
        Logger.info("oldu2");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            textBuilder.append(line);
            textBuilder.append("\n");
        }
        isThereAnySavedFile = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Logger.info("oldu3");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return textBuilder;
}
```

Comment: In the logcat you should see the line that throws the exception. And you should try to get the written file on your pc to check what is inside.

Comment: `String textFromSD = String.valueOf(read());`. read() is returning a StringBuilder instance. What would String.valueOf make of this?  Rethink!